# NSTableView data is updated after scrolling down the columns

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, reloaddata

I have two table views synchronised together and both are bound to same array controller. In the first table view the columns are editable and that the corresponding column values should reflect in the other table view. There is an option of copy values from one column to rest of columns in the first(editable) table view. The problem is : when I edit one column value and copy values to the other columns in the first table view, the values are not reflected in the second table view until I scroll across the columns till last column in the first table view.
I tried to reload data for both table view/ also tried to call the reload data in `performselectorinmainthread` / even in `dispatch_async`, but still the values are not reflected in the second table view until I scroll down in the first table view.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.firstTableView reloadData];
        [self.secondTableView reloadData];
        [self.firstTableView setNeedsDisplay];
        [self.secondTableView setNeedsDisplay];
    });



   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

-(void) updateTable
{
       [self.firstTableView reloadData];
       [self.secondTableView reloadData];
       [self.firstTableView setNeedsDisplay];
       [self.secondTableView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Let me know incase I am missing something in my code.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. Post the code relevant to the actual copying of the information. I suspect you're modifying your data "behind the array controller's back". Also, force-updating the table won't work for the same reason - you're short-circuiting the bindings mechanism, which results in your table re-displaying before its underlying model changes are available.